# Creating Custom Processor In Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I am building an custom processor to process flow file , to process the flow file i need to read an CSV file from my local file system. I created an proerty descriptor CSV_PATH as follows

```
public static final PropertyDescriptor CSV_PATH = new 
PropertyDescriptor
.Builder().name("CSV Path")
.displayName("CSV Path")
.description("CSV Path Reader")
.required(true)
.addValidator(StandardValidators.NON_EMPTY_VALIDATOR)
.build();



@Override

protected void init(final ProcessorInitializationContext context) {

final List<PropertyDescriptor> descriptors = new 
ArrayList<PropertyDescriptor>();

descriptors.add(JSON_PATH);

descriptors.add(CSV_PATH);

this.descriptors = Collections.unmodifiableList(descriptors);



final Set<Relationship> relationships = new HashSet<Relationship>();

relationships.add(SUCCESS);

this.relationships = Collections.unmodifiableSet(relationships);

}
```

Now I wants to get the value of CSV_PATH property set in UI while configuring processor. I am not able to get the CSV_PATH value. Also If I hardcode filepath in code then still I am not able to read CSV from local file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the following code to retrieve the value of the [`PropertyDescriptor`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#property_descriptor) from the [`ProcessContext`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html#process_context):

```
@Override
public void onTrigger(final ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) {
    FlowFile flowFile = session.get();
    if (flowFile == null) {
        return;
    }

    final String csvPath = context.getProperty(CSV_PATH).getValue();

    // Do something with csvPath

}
```

If you decide to support [NiFi Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html) in that property descriptor, you will also want to evaluate for that:

`final String csvPath = context.getProperty(CSV_PATH).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue();`

There are additional method overrides for that, including flowfile attributes, variable registry, custom decorators, etc.

This is documented in the [Apache NiFi Developer's Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html). I recently did a [presentation at Dataworks Summit Barcelona 2019](https://github.com/alopresto/slides/tree/master/dws_barcelona_2019) covering custom processor development with some best practices included and examples that may be helpful. You can also look at any existing processor in the NiFi codebase to see examples.